# What is an ".eps vector die line?"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

[image]

I am getting a special cut sticker printed out (not sure if you can see from the photo. I am getting 25 of them printed. I sent the printer the sticker, with a cut line and a bleed line. The stickers will be small 2in x 1in.

The printer keeps telling me I need to send them an ***.eps vector die line***

I've done die lines before and thought sending them the cut line and bleed line was it but apparently I'm wrong.

*What are they asking for?*

Answer (score 3):

I'm not expert but looking it up shows that a sticker dieline is the cut line the die will use. On the graphic with your sticker art draw a big arrow to the cut line and print in bold "This is the cut line".

Make the line bold and obvious.

This site below says the dieline should be 1/8th" thick to allow for cutting error.

Take your graphic with the sticker art, cut line and bleed line (not the arrow and words), save it as an .eps (that makes it vector) and send it to them.

Writing this made me think maybe they need the actual line to be definitely in vector. If your art was ever saved as a .jpg or .bmp or other raster file types than the line may not be vector. With your illustrator file open draw a new cut line with the pen or line tool, save as an .eps and send.

If they still won't accept it then ask them what they are looking for specifically, with examples and possibly a template.

https://99designs.com/blog/design-tutorials/how-to-design-a-die-cut-sticker/
http://blog.jakprints.com/die-line-tutorial/how-to-create-a-dieline

Comment: Thank you so much! This is actually what I was doing while I was waiting for answers to my question, so hopefully this is what they are looking for. Thanks again! Extremely helpful.

Comment: @BrittanyWashington Please note that if you use a diecut, you won't be able to keep the drop shadow that we can notice on your picture, unless you print on a transparent sticker...

Answer (score -2):

No one will set you up a die line for 25 stickers, it wouldn't be cost effective.
Get some full sheet sticker stock paper, rated to go through the printer you are using. set them up multi on a page and create the cut line in a layer so that is barely visible and cut them yourself with an art knife with a metal ruler.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the question: what should she tell her printer, what are they asking for.

Comment: Right, they want me to setup the dieline for the 25 stickers. They said if they have to do it, it will cost $75.00 which I am trying to avoid because I honestly have done dielines before. But this method you have posed is also feasible and I will do it next time around. Thank you for the suggestion.